# building a simple regex for @Pattern

Tags: regex, validation

I need to validate a String that should represent a house number. unfortunately in my country (probably others as well) these house numbers can consists of numbers AND letters. because of this I cant just use an Integer, which would make this a lot easier to validate. I've been looking around for explanations and i actually find lots of them but i'm having serious difficulties grasping this subject. since i just need a (simple?) pattern just this once, i hope someone can help me out here.

so what i exactly need is a regex pattern that validates if the inserted string has any number (but probably a maximum of 4) of positive numbers followed by maximum ONE letter. What would be the correct expression for this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you need is this:

`^\d{1,4}[a-zA-Z]?$`

Explanation:

`^\d{1,4}`   this is an anchor `^` for the beginning of the string, followed by 1-4 digits

`[a-zA-Z]?$` this is any letter, 0 or 1 times, at the end of the string (`$`)

Comment: In no javascript engine the most robust anchor with validation is \A and \z

Comment: Thanks you for your help and explanation!! I just want to add that I had to escape the "\" character by typing it twice "\\". just in case if someone else finds this and cant get it to work.

Comment: What I gave you was the regex itself. Depending on the context, you may need to escape the \ character, but not always. The regex literal would be `/^\d{1,4}[a-zA-Z]?$/`, but a RegExp object defined with a string requires an extra slash because of the meaning of slashes in strings: `new RegExp("^\\d{1,4}[a-zA-Z]?$")`

Answer (score 1):

In [JavaScript RegExp notation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp):

```
/^\d{1,4}\[A-Za-z]?$/
```

You can use it like this:

```
if("2234B".match(/^\d{1,4}[A-Za-z]?$/) !== null) {
    // String matched, do something
}
```

Explanation:

- ^ means "Beginning of input", to make sure that you do not allow something before the digits
- \d{1,4} means "1 to 4 digits"
- [A-Za-z]? means "zero or one of any character"
- $ means "End of input", to make sure that you do not allow something after the character